# how to count html body char in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get all chars in a website by JavaScript.

For example:

```
<p>aaa<B>a</B></p>   -> 4

<div>         ->16
<p>aaaa</p>
<p>aaaa</p>
<p>aaaa</p>
<p>aaaa</p>
</div>
........

<body>...</body>  ->X
```

I have tried something like `$(document.body).text();` to count but it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following

```
$('body').text().length;
```

Without whitespace count between words

```
 $('body').text().replace(/ +/g, "").length;
```

Also, this is a bad idea, as your body may contain CSS and JS files. That too may include in the count. So surround the html you want to count using `div` with `id`. And then you count the characters of that particular `div` using respective `id`.

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ejngm65r/)

Comment: You don't need `split()` here

Answer (score 0):

The `$("body").text()` return text content of body that may contain space. You should remove space using [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and get length of final text using [`string.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length).

```js
$("body").text().replace(/\s+/g, "").length;
```

If body has `<script>` or `<style>` tag, you should filter selected text using [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

```
var length = $("body").contents().filter(function(){
  return (this.localName != "script" && this.localName != "style") ? true : false;
}).text().replace(/\s+/g, "").length;
```

```js
var length = $("body").contents().filter(function(){
  return (this.localName != "script" && this.localName != "style") ? true : false;
}).text().replace(/\s+/g, "").length;
console.log(length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>aaa<B>a</B></p>
<div>
  <p>aaaa</p>
  <p>aaaa</p>
  <p>aaaa</p>
  <p>aaaa</p>
</div>
<script>//script</script>
<style>style</style>
```